# this.each is not a function error in google geochart

Tags: javascript, magento, google-visualization

```
<div id = "geochart" >< /div>

<script type = "text/javascript" >
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAcChart);
function drawAcChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
    ['South America', 600],
    ['Canada', 500],
    ['France', 600],
    ['Russia', 700],
    ['Australia', 600]
  ]);
 var options = {
    displayMode: 'text'
  };
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

I have above code to get geograph. but i am getting this.each is not a function error in geochart div . Can any give solution please.

Comment: remove white space from `div` for starters --> `<div id="geochart"></div>` (vs. above)

Comment: I removed white space and tried but still getting same error .

Comment: where is load statement? --> `google.charts.load` needs to be called before `setOnLoadCallback`

Comment: I am calling related load functions and js files in another file i.e. base file. I am able to get all other google charts like line chart and pie chart .But geochart is giving this error .

Comment: are you loading 'geochart' package, along wth 'corechart'?

Comment: What is that geochart package . Could you please tell me that package .

Answer (score 0):

packages are loaded in the `load` statement...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawCharts,
  packages: ['corechart', 'geochart']  // <-- packages for regular charts and geo charts
});
```

regular charts like line, column, and scatter, all use the `'corechart'` package

specialty charts, like the geo chart, typically have their own package that needs loading...

be sure to load the `'geochart'` package...

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawCharts,

  // packages for regular charts, and geo charts
  packages: ['corechart', 'geochart']
});

function drawCharts() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
    ['Germany', 200],
    ['United States', 300],
    ['Brazil', 400],
    ['Canada', 500],
    ['France', 600],
    ['RU', 700]
  ]);

  var chartGeo = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
  chartGeo.draw(data);

  var chartCol = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chartCol.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="regions_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have put that too in load function and tried but getting same error . Later I found solution when i update prototype js from 1.7 to 1.7.3 version . Is this correct way to fix the issue.